# Django: How to create superuser with custom fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I have a custom `User` model in my `models.py` and custom `UserManager` as well. My custom `User` model has `username` field with changed name to `login` and same is updated in `UserManager` as well. Everything goes fine, but when I try to create superuser using command `python manage.py createsuperuser`, it asks for `login` but it does not ask for `email` which at the end gives me this error:

```
TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'
```

My custom `User` model is:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'login'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

My custom `UserManager` is:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, login, email, password, is_staff, is_admin, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        now = timezone.now()
        email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(
            login=login,
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_active=True,
            is_admin=is_admin,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now, 
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_user(self, login, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user = self._create_user(login, email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, login, email, password, **extra_fields):
        user=self._create_user(login, email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

        return user
```

and in `admin.py` I have:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('login', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'last_login')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active', 
            'is_staff', 
            'is_admin',
            'groups', 
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                'classes': ('wide',),
                'fields': ('login', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
            }
        ),
    )

    list_display = ('login', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_admin', 'last_login')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_admin', 'is_active', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email', 'login',)
    ordering = ('email', 'login',)
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add `'email'` in the `REQUIRED_FIELDS` variable in my `User` model definition. i.e.

I had to change following line:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

to

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

Comment: REQUIRED_FIELDS fields should be in Abstract user model?

Answer (score 0):

You gotta create a new form in your app and then reference it into your admin.py module.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(...)
    """ other fields ... """
```

then go into your admin.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = SignUpForm # Set your custom form whatever it is

    """ Now go to the base class(built-in UserAdmin) there's a bunch of
    other fields which you can set. you have to override the add_fieldsets
    and include the custom fields you added in your form also to show up 
    these fields you have to override fieldsets as well """
```